# How to implement interactive bar chart in React native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, bar-chart

I am working on React Native App project where I have to display an interactive bar chart. **As shown in attracted screenshot**. The app is working on both iOS and Android devices. Where we are currently providing minimal iOS and Android app support as following:

```sh
1. Android 4.3.x / Jelly Bean / API level 18 
2. iOS 9.0 or later
3. iPadOS 9.0 or later.
```

### Requirement:

1. In a bar chart, every bar will be clickable. When the user clicks on any bar, the relative information will be display below the chart accordingly.
2. Suggested chart library should match our minimal app support in both operating systems (iOS & Android).

### Current dependencies

Currently, the project is running with the following React framework versions:

1. React Native: 0.63.4
2. React: 16.13.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After doing lots of research I found following chart libraries:

**1. react-native-chart-kit**

- It provide bar chart but its documentation is not showing click/press event with bar chart. So asked the question on its thread. Also found it is using
- Weekly Downloads:11,959
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit
- https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit
- I also asked question for minimal OS support and bar click event but didn't get any response from that team. See the URLs https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit-example/issues/15 , https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/issues/485

**2. React Native Charts Wrapper** [react-native-charts-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-charts-wrapper)

- Weekly Downloads:2,804
- It is built on `MPAndroidChart(v3.1.0)` & `Charts(v3.3.0)`, support both android & iOS. These libraries are very popular Native charting library. This library is also having good support and documentation.
- People suggesting to use it. [react native chart/graph library that supports user onPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124540/react-native-chart-graph-library-that-supports-user-onpress)

**3. React Native Pure Chart** [react-native-pure-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pure-chart)

- Weekly Downloads: 536
- [oksktank/react-native-pure-chart](https://github.com/oksktank/react-native-pure-chart)

**4. react-chartjs-2**

- [reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2)
- YouTube video :[Using Chart.js With React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly-9VTXJlnA)

**5. Victory**

- [FormidableLabs/victory](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory)
- [VictoryBar](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-bar)

**Article on Quora**: See the link where user article shows good react-native charting tools
https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-react-native-charting-tool

### *Final Conclusion*

I have found [React Native Charts Wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-charts-wrapper) is suitable for me, even I have tested in `Android 5.1` and `iOS 9`, in both device bar chart is working fine and didn't fine any crash or bug. The library is also working fine with latest devices. Also tested with `React-Native 0.64` and it is working fine at my end.

Comment: After your usage do you still feel you made the right decision? Have you run in to any pitfalls or major issues with React Native Charts Wrapper? Did you have a lot of control over the styling?

Comment: @Ryan-Llaver - As such we didn't find any issue or challenge with Chart Wrapper.  It is working fine in all major iOS and Android devices. Yes, we face some styling limitation even I have raised my query in its git repository. See this url https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/issues/793